# Unable to get all predefined Presets from AWS Elastic Transcoder

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I am trying to get the all Presets from AWS Elastic Transcoder but the following code returns only 50 out of 62

```
List<Preset> presets = amazonElasticTranscoder.listPresets().getPresets();
```

1. How do I get all presets (include custom presets)??
2. Is there any possible to get Preset using presetName??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The responses from AWS come in pages of 50. To get the next page, take the `nextPageToken` from the `ListPresetsResult` you got, and use it in another call:

```
ListPresetsRequest request = new ListPresetsRequest();
request.setPageToken(result.getNextPageToken());
amazonElasticTranscoder.listPresets(request);
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to find a preset by name in the Java API.